# Update Y in once cell if other cell has text

Tags: excel, vba

Need to solve the below code
if in column B the text value is "EA" the in column M should update "Y" but its not updating

```
Dim y As Workbook
Dim lr1, lr2 As Long
With y.Sheets("MARM")
    If .Range("B5").Value = "EA" Then
        lr2 = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("M5:M" & lr2).Value = "Y"
    End If
End With
```

Comment: Assuming this is your entire code for a sub, you should be getting an error, since you haven't set `y`. I.e. use `Set y = ActiveWorkbook` before your `With` statement. Depending on the value of `lr2` (= the last row in Column A), you might be setting the value to `"Y"` for a whole bunch of cells, not just `Range("M5")`

Comment: does column A have the same number of rows like column M?

Answer (score -1):

M column will be blank, column A is for to identify last row
the data looks like this..

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtOUh.png)

Comment: If this is not a solution then please update the screenshot in the query by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72184185/update-y-in-once-cell-if-other-cell-has-text/72185923#72185923) it

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).